# use repeater to read values from sql

Tags: .net, sql

How can i use a repeater to display values from sql server?

Comment: Please be more specific. What _exactly_ are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortage of tutorials for this on the internet.  [Here's](http://blogs.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/) one I quickly found.  There are [others](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp%20.net%20repeater%20example).